# How to split url to get url path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have constructed a url path that are pointing to different hostname `www.mysite.com`, so for example:

```
var myMainSite = 'www.mymainsite.com' + '/somepath';
```

so this is equivalent to `www.mymainsite.com/path/path/needthispath/somepath`.

How I'm doing it now is like the code below and this gives me a bunch of indexes of the url in the `console.log`.

```
var splitUrl = myMainSite.split('/');
```

`console.log` looks like:

```
0: http://
1: www.
2: mysite.com
3: path
4: path
5: needthispath
6: somepath
```

and I concat them like `splitUrl[5]+'/'+splitUrl[6]` and it doesn't look pretty at all.

So my question is how to split/remove url location `http://www.mymainsite.com/` to get the url path `needthispath/somepath` in js? Is there a quicker and cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Can you try that :

document.location.pathname

Comment: @AyyoubDahhane this would only work if the current url is the URL he is aiming to split. The `I have constructed a url path that are pointing to _different_ hostname` makes me believe otherwise

Comment: @N.J.Dawson Yeah you are correct.

Comment: @nCore what is it that you didn't like with my answer that you didn't accept it? was it not explaining well?

Comment: @inanc oh I did click the tick not sure why it didn't show up. Ah nvm could be because I like the other one too so had to wait for few seconds.

Comment: @nCore ok thx :))

Answer (score 84, accepted):

## First solution (URL object)

The **URL object** can be used for parsing, constructing, normalizing, encoding URLs, and so on.

```js
var url = 'http://www.mymainsite.com/somepath/path2/path3/path4';

var pathname = new URL(url).pathname;

console.log(pathname);
```

> The URL interface represents an object providing static methods used
>   for creating object URLs.

- See [the documentation for URL interface on Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Properties)
- The [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=url) is pretty good in 2017 (~ 90% but not IE11 nor below)

---

## Second solution (a kind of a hack)

```js
var urlHack = document.createElement('a');
urlHack.href = 'http://www.mymainsite.com/somepath/path2/path3/path4';

console.log(urlHack.pathname);

// you can even call this object with these properties:
// protocol, host, hostname, port, pathname, hash, search, origin
```

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you use the split function and work from there.
The split function will break your URL out fully and from there you just need to look for the second last and last items.

Here is an example:

```
var initial_url = 'http://www.mymainsite.com/path/path/needthispath/somepath';
var url = initial_url .split( '/' );

var updated_url= document.location.hostname + '/' + url[ url.length - 2 ] + '/' + url[ url.length - 1 ];
```

Comment: that's what I'm using now using the .split function. But I found a way now. :) thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API, though support is variable.

Alternatively, you could use [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/).

Both allow you to get different parts of an URL, as well as build new URLs from parts.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function url($url) {
  var url = $url.split( '//' );
  if (url[0] === "http:" || url[0] === "https:") {
    var protocol = url[0] + "//";
    var host = url[1].split( '/' )[0];
    url = protocol + host;
    var path = $url.split(url)[1];
    return {
      protocol: protocol,
      host: host,
      path: path
    };
  }
}

var $url = url("http://www.mymainsite.com/path/path/needthispath/somepath");

console.log($url.protocol); // http://
console.log($url.host); // www.mymainsite.com
console.log($url.path); // /path/path/needthispath/somepath
```