# Extracting data from string by splitting URL twice

Tags: javascript, url, split, google-tag-manager

I would like to achieve the following:

I have a URL: https://www.example.com/Place/Name.html?randomtext

I need to return "Name" only on outgoing links.

I thought it would work by doing the following:

```js
    function() {
      if ({{outgoing link}})
      var Name= {{Click URL}};
      return Name.split("/")[2];
      return Name.split("?")[0];
    }
```

I already managed to get "place" by doing:

```js
    function() {
          if ({{outgoing link}})
          var Name= {{Click URL}};
          return Name.split("/")[2];
```

Comment: I am not 100% I get what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split url to get url path in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334400/how-to-split-url-to-get-url-path-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the filename ("Name") would be to do:

```
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1).split(".")[0]
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-roman-uerpcp?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what u want:

```
const url = 'https://www.example.com/Place/Name.html?randomtext'

 function extractSliceFromUrl() {
      return url.split("/")[4].split(".")[0];
    }
```

```js
const url = 'https://www.example.com/Place/Name.html?randomtext'

 function extractSliceFromUrl() {
      return url.split("/")[4].split(".")[0];
    }
    
    console.log(extractSliceFromUrl(url))
```

```
    console.log(extractSliceFromUrl(url))
```